# EditText com no máximo uma linha

Tags: android

Vejo que pra escrever em somente em uma linha no `EditText` precisa ser com `android:maxLines="1"` e `android:inputType="text"`, mas eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de fazer isso com `android:inputType="number"`, pq só quero que o teclado de números apareça

Exemplo:

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="number"
    android:digits="0123456789"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="end"/>
```

Só que quando faço isso, quando chega no final da linha ele vai pra outra linha, mantendo o tamanho do layout de uma linha, e sem o `android:maxLines="1"` ele aumenta o tamanho do layout do `EditText`

Comment: Do jeito que você está fazendo, não está passando de 1 linha, está correto. Porém, quando acaba o espaço pra colocar os número, eles tem que pra algum lugar  se você continuar digitando. Já tentou a hipótese de limitar a quantidade de caracteres digitados?

Comment: Eu entendi essa parte, é o correto, mas a questão é de saber se existe alguma forma de ele se comportar igual quando é `android:inputType="text"`, de ficar na mesma linha e ir dando scroll lateral no `EditText` e não numa nova linha. Mas acho que não é possível, deve ter um motivo para tal limitação.

Answer (score 1):

Faz tempo, então espero que você tenha conseguido. Caso não, basta utilizar `singleLine="true"`:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
  android:id="@+id/edt_observacao"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:imeOptions="actionNext"
  android:inputType="textMultiLine"
  android:singleLine="true" />
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, não estou desenvolvendo mais para Android e não tenho como replicar a situação no momento para testar. Não aceitarei como resposta porque na [documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#singleLine) o `singleLine` está depreciado.